# Identify best GridsearchCV scoring metric for food prediction in XGBoost

Tags: python-3.x, xgboost, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I am using GridSearchCV to find the best parameter that help me tune XGBoost for a food prediction algorithm.

I am struggling to identify the best scoring metric that would result in the best profit (sales margin minus wastage costs) as this is ultimately what I am looking for. In running the script below and plugging it into the data (I reserved some data for testing only), I noticed that a better R2 seems to be better than a better RMSE in obtaining a higher profit. But I am struggling to find an explanation which will help me guide to the best scoring method.

Here some infos on the situation:
It costs me 6 USD to produce the product and 9 USD to sell, so my margin is 3 USD. Therefore my wastage is 6 USD multiplied by (production minus sales quantities), whereas my earnings are sales quantities multiplied by 3. 
Example: I produce 100, sell 70, waste 30 my earnings are 70*3 - 30*6 = 30
So I have an imbalance between sales and wastage.

Main Question: Which scoring metric puts a higher penalty weight on the over-prediction?

My current code:

```
X = consumption[feature_names]
y = consumption['Meal1']

data_dmatrix = xgb.DMatrix(data=X,label=y)

# Create the parameter grid: gbm_param_grid
gbm_param_grid = {
    'min_child_weight':[1, 2],
    'gamma': [0.05,0.06],
    'reg_alpha':range(1, 2),
    'colsample_bytree': [0.22, 0.23],
    'n_estimators': range(28, 29),
    'max_depth': range(3, 8),
    'reg_alpha':range(1, 2),
    'reg_lambda':range(1, 2),
    'subsample': [0.7,0.8,0.9],
    'learning_rate': [0.1,0.2],


}
fixed_params = {'objective':'reg:squarederror','booster':'gbtree' }

# Instantiate the regressor: gbm
gbm = xgb.XGBRegressor(**fixed_params)

# Perform grid search: grid_mse
grid_mse = GridSearchCV(estimator=gbm, param_grid=gbm_param_grid, scoring="r2", cv=5, verbose=1)


# Fit grid_mse to the data
grid_mse.fit(X,y)

# Print the best parameters and lowest RMSE
print("Best parameters found: ", grid_mse.best_params_)
print("Lowest Score found: ", np.sqrt(np.abs(grid_mse.best_score_)))
```

Comment: IIUC, from your description its not a regression task, rather its an optimization problem to find maximum output over given inputs.

Comment: The regression task is to predict the number of sales. But then it is an optimization problem. My questions is if there is a way to include the optimization problem into the regression task already

Comment: I think you could try to build you own metric/scorer to include this. See some doc here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.make_scorer.html